# python install package error and adafruit pureio

Tags: python, spi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnGFr.png)

Hi i don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Edit your question with code or error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some timeout error. Either you are behind a proxy network which block you or there is some issue with the connectivity.

If you are behind a proxy you can try installing using the command

```
user@CNDAMSTECHP3 MINGW32 ~
$ pip install adafruit-pureio --proxy=http://<url>:<port>
Collecting adafruit-pureio
  Downloading Adafruit_PureIO-0.2.1-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: adafruit-pureio
Successfully installed adafruit-pureio-0.2.1
```